# pyspark - weighted moving average through uneven period lengths

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying calculate a weighted (based on duration) moving average of a dataframe with uneven timestamp records.
Below is an example df.

```
+-----+-------------------+
|value|               date|
+-----+-------------------+
|  9.0|2017-03-15 11:42:00|
|  7.0|2017-03-16 13:02:00|
|  7.0|2017-03-16 19:02:00|
|  7.0|2017-03-16 21:38:00|
|  7.0|2017-03-16 21:58:00|
|  6.0|2017-03-18 10:07:00|
| 22.0|2017-03-18 12:21:00|
| 21.0|2017-03-20 23:21:00|
| 19.0|2017-03-21 10:21:00|
| 17.0|2017-03-04 11:01:00|
| 16.0|2017-03-09 18:41:00|
+-----+-------------------+
```

I have tried to use rangeBetween but I think it only takes simple average
Then tried to use `pyspark.sql.functions.window` method with `w = window('date','7 days','5 minutes')`, and calculate weighted average with a `udf`, but I haven't been able to even calculate a simple average because it took forever to calculate it.

```
w = window('date','7 days','5 minutes')
win = Window.partitionBy(w).orderBy(df['date'].asc())
new_df = df.withColumn('average',avg('value').over(win))
```

I was also advised to transform the table to an evenly distributed time period.
Which one do you advise & why, and how to approach window sliding and filling?
I am a newbie in pyspark

Thanks